# how to send my java class object in internet

Tags: java, serialization

I have a simple java class object. I can send the byte code to any of my friends through network. So what is the problem by sending an object without serializing it? Why seriazation is required to send an object. Can't we send it directly?

Comment: Yes. You can send it through email.

Comment: If your friends are JVM processes then you have to serialize. else email the .java file.

Comment: you want to send the class or the object?

Comment: He wants to send the byte code and wants to know why he should serialize an object..

Answer (score 0):

By serializing you convert your object to the stream of bytes containing your class definition and the props of your object. On the other hand, what's the problem serializing it? It's just the way to do it.

Comment: Serialization is required if he try to send it to another working java system. If he want to send it to any of his friends, email is good.

Comment: Email an object? Could you explain, how is it possible? And what does a friend supposed to do with it? Print it and hang it on the wall? Object is needed for the system.

Comment: Exactly. That was the question :-)

Comment: if i have a class A and inside this class i am having a object of another class B. If i send the byte code of class A then i am tranporting the object of class B - @iozee

Comment: @Alexander thank you for information about your house. If you want to be constructive - could you please work directly with manasi to make his question clear?

Comment: @Alexander, u may be perfect in java n its concepts but i am new to it. So, i can't understand the bookish concepts . i need something demo  that you can show me how the seriazation is done clearly.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written any single test class? No practice - no knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your object can contain unserializable objects like InputStreams or DatabaseConnections. If your object (or its predecessors) implements interface Serializable, you code will not compile till the serialization is realy possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, byte code is what represents a JVM readable format while your serialized object contains behavior and states (instance variables) of an object. they are altogether different thing.

reasons why you would want to send serialized object on network.

1. Your object's state keep changing, so at any point of time you would want to capture its state and store/send on  network.
2. You may want to store your object's state not in your machine but someone else's.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is managing state of object with client server communication. If you are not making Serializable then it will not manage state of object. if you will try then pass one object from server to client without serialization, it will provide u null object value. so it is indicate that the object which u want to receive at client that is not same as u send. simply through serialization it is not creating new object everytime.so it must required.

Answer (score 0):

`Object's` state lie's inside `JVM` . How any other `JVM` come to know about the state of your object which is inside your `JVM` , you can transfer blueprint(Class) of your object to your friend via `E-Mail` `ftp` or any other file transfer medium but if you have to transfer `object` across the `JVM` then you need to persist the state of object and thus you need serialization.